# Realizar SELECT randômico

Tags: mysql, sql-select

Tenho uma tabela onde desejo sempre mostrar um único registro de forma randômica.

Estou fazendo assim:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `tabela` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Vejo que dessa forma os mesmos registros repetem muito, existe uma melhor forma de se fazer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com MySQL 4.1 ou mais recente, podes fazer o seguinte:

```
SELECT id FROM tabela WHERE id >= (SELECT FLOOR(MAX(id) * RAND()) FROM tabela) ORDER BY id LIMIT 1;
```

Nota que este método só funciona em tabelas com IDs únicos.